# Joi: "tel" is not allowed to be empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

Joi is returning the following error even though `tel` is set to be **optional**. How do we fix this?

Thanks.

> Error: Joi Failed: ValidationError: child "tel" fails because ["tel" is not allowed to be empty]

---

```
//Define Joi schema
const schema = {
    email: Joi.string().required().email({
        errorLevel: 64,
        minDomainAtoms: 2 
    }).min(6),
    tel: Joi.string().optional().min(10).max(10),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(8).max(64)
}

//Check inputs
const { error, value } = Joi.validate({ 
    email: args.email, 
    tel: tel, 
    password: args.password 
}, schema)
```

Comment: [*"Note that empty strings are not allowed by default and must be enabled with `allow('')`."*](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.6.0/API.md#string---inherits-from-any)

Comment: Thanks. That solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> ...empty strings are not allowed by default and must be enabled with
>   `allow('')`. However, if you want to specify a default value in case
>   of empty string you have to use a different pattern:
>   `Joi.string().empty('').default('default value')`. This tells Joi that
>   the empty string should be considered as an empty value (instead of
>   invalid) and which value to use as default.

Reference: [Joi v10.6.0 Documetations](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.6.0/API.md#string---inherits-from-any)

In your case:

```
tel: Joi.string().optional().allow('').min(10).max(10)
```

Comment: How can I do this with Joi.email() ?